# Looking for exactly meaning of "all down the line" in a children's song

Tags: phrase-meaning

I heard a song: **Our school will shine today**

(youtube song link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfhO_3i9Apo)

**Lyrics are as follows:**

> Our school will shine today, our school will shine
>
> Our school will shine today, **all down the line**
>
> Our school will shine today, our school will shine
>
> When the sun goes down, when the moon goes up
>
> Our school will shine

I looked up "all down the line".

**Farlex Dictionary of Idioms**

> - In the future

**The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer**

> - All the way, throughout.
> - At a future point or end.

The phrase "**all down the line**" in the song confuses me.

Does it mean

**1.** Our school will shine sometime in the future ?

**2.** Our school will shine completely and thoroughly?

**3.** Our school will shine completely and thoroughly in the future ?

What does it actually mean in the song?

Comment: Try this tactic: search for ['all down the line' define](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27all+down+the+line%27+define)

Comment: @JBH I know that. That is what my first comment (now deleted by me)  was meant to convey. That Farley does not say that *all down the line* means *in the future* but it says *down the line* does. Perhaps that's clearer.

Comment: Please be more than careful about the meaning of anything clearly written by non-native speakers. As JBH said, *Like most idioms, there are several different meanings. In this context, "all down the line" means "all along the way" or "in every way"* but that might not be true of anything written even by well-educated adult Asiatics, let alone school-children.

Answer (score 1):

Like most idioms, there are several different meanings.  In this context, "all down the line" means "all along the way" or "in every way."  It suggests a line of students are all well mannered and behaved, or all the rules are being followed, or all preparations are complete.

Comment: I'm sorry and I suggest it has nothing at all to do with any *line of students*.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, you may have missed the point (and the cultural underpinnings of the artists).

Comment: *Cultural underpinnings* is an interesting expression but it doesn't alter the fact that guesses about what a group on un-skilled non-natives might have meant are bound to be dubious.

*Our school will shine today, all down the line* might be the best possible translation of something with a clear meaning in the original language.

D'you really not think to suggest it's more than some sort of emphasis, in English, seems rather rash.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, of course it's an emphasis, but to suggest it's nothing more than that frankly robs the artists of respect.  Artists usually have a reason beyond finding a rhyme for using any phrase.  Curiously, from an oriental perspective, the phrase has both meaning and importance - despite your efforts to deny that.  I have noticed that this site tends to perceive the use of English principally from a British perspective, occasionally from an American perspective, and ignores the rest of the planet.  What a disservice that is to the many people seeking to understand our language.

Comment: JBH nothing, including *all down the line* suggests a line of students are all well mannered and behaved *or* all the rules are being followed *or* all preparations are complete; to suggest that says more about the thinker than the thought.

My warning was against subjecting a translation of such a vague concept to the torsion that twisted *to suggest it's more than some sort of emphasis… seems rather rash* into *it's nothing more than that*.

Of course artists have reasons but what makes you think even most of them get it right, or that you’d know what this one meant?

Comment: I've said before on Stack Exchange that if language is to be defined by description of use, rather than prescription of theory then Chinese or Indian English will set the standard but wait!

I’ve heard it said more people are learning English in China than live in the USA… but US English is those people’s native tongue. Chinese students are learning a foreign language which stops them being comparable.

Still, India is a different kettle of Kedgeree. She does use English as a first language, so democratically should wipe the floor with every other variant, including yours and mine.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The line just means all the way. It is after all poetry or song writing, not written text. Line rhymes with shine, I think that's the point. I agree though, there is no "line of students" but rather an entire set of activities and situations.

Comment: Lambie that might be true and I think you've moved into pure guesswork, supported by more hope than anything else… which is allowed, of course, but hardly any basis for anything but hope… Can you really still not see the difference between imposing  the various suggested interpretations on the language, and imposing the language on their suggestions?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, If you indeed have better insight into the matter than the rest of us, then stop wasting our time with these pedantic complaints and post your answer for the community to review.

Comment: I'm sorry Lambie Dredged this up again and I didn't take the trouble to read the whole back-story again and notice the previous bumping. Since you put it that way, JBH, then why don't you stop wasting everyone's time defending  pointless speculation so tenuous it's unlikely the idea could be supported by anyone did speak both languages fluently?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, Post... your... answer...  Because right now your reputation among the people who read this post is that you're an arrogant troll.  If you have a good point, then please, by all means, post your answer and prove me wrong.  If you refuse to post an answer and instead post another comment, I'll invite the moderators to push this entire conversation into chat and it will be removed from the answer.